# Run Cucumber scenario outline by range on line numbers

Tags: cucumber

I know it's possible to run specific examples in cucumber

```
cucumber tests/features/my.feature:141 #just example 141
cucumber tests/features/my.feature:141:151 #just examples 141 & 151
```

What is the syntax to run a range of examples from 141 to 151?

```
cucumber tests/features/my.feature:141-151 #this does not work
```

If it helps, Here is the Scenario Outline snippet... assuming 'tc-44' is on line 141 in the file

```
Scenario Outline: running scenario subset of examples 
Given we are testing a subset
 And it is a scenario outline with many examples
Then we can run a subset by providing a range
Examples:
| test-case |
| tc-44 |
| tc-45 |
| tc-46 |
| tc-47 |
| tc-48 |
| tc-49 |
...
| tc-100 |
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the command line you can run specific scenarios from the same feature file using a colon between the line numbers, like this:

```
cucumber tests/features/my.feature:37:52
```

If scenarios are defined at lines 37 and 52, both would be executed by cucumber.

You can likewise run specific examples by referencing their line number. In your case, this would work:

```
cucumber tests/features/my.feature:141:142:143:144:145:146:147:148:149:150:151
```

Cucumber will execute the example found at each line number.